# Opening a new window in PHP using PrestaShop

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I need help opening a new window by executing the validation code. The thing is that I need this when the next PHP file is run.

```
<?php

class hhpaymentvalidationModuleFrontController extends ModuleFrontController
{


    /**
     * Validation du paiement standard
     * Puis redirection vers la page de succès de commande
     */
    public function postProcess()
    {
         $cart = $this->context->cart;

       $this->abrir("http://davivienda.com");
//       0abrir("http://davivienda.com");


        if ($cart->id_customer == 0 || $cart->id_address_delivery == 0 || $cart->id_address_invoice == 0 || !$this->module->active) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');
        }

        $customer = new Customer($cart->id_customer);

        if (!Validate::isLoadedObject($customer)) {
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1');
        }

        $currency = $this->context->currency;
        $total = (float)$cart->getOrderTotal(true, Cart::BOTH);

        //La command passe directement en statut payé
        $this->module->validateOrder((int)$cart->id, Configuration::get('PS_OS_PAYMENT'), $total, $this->module->displayName, null, array(), (int)$currency->id, false, $customer->secure_key);
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation&id_cart='.(int)$cart->id.'&id_module='.(int)$this->module->id.'&id_order='.$this->module->currentOrder.'&key='.$customer->secure_key);
    }

public function abrir( $param ) 
  {

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
    echo "window.open( '{$param}', 'ventana1', 'scrollbars=0, width=300, height=300' )";
    echo '</script>';  
  } 

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I translated your title into English to make more people understand you. I've also corrected some of your spelling and removed unnecessary text in your question, such as "Good friends", "please help" and repeated phrases. You might want to update your question with a more thorough explanation of what your problem is and why the code posted does not work. Does it throw any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can't open new window/tab through a PHP script because it is server-side language. But you can pass some variable within your redirect url and use it in client side. Like

```
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&step=1&popup=1');
```

then use jQuery to open new window with your URL

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  if (searchParams.has('popup')) {
    window.open('Your URL', 'window name', 'window settings')
  }
});
```

Comment: I have two doubts.
1. in tools :: redirect only redirects to another page does not open a new window.
2. where should I put the jQuaery on my page validation.php

Comment: You do not necessarily need to redirect to another page, you can stay on the same page but after validation add a new parameter to your URL and new smarty variable if you need these. And a script you can add in the main js file global.js

Comment: @ Alexander Grosul - If that is precisely what I need, open a new window with the payment gateway, or I do not know if there is a form that after paying for a payment api I returned a validation of payment